Logstash - Grok - The correct syntax to match against multiple patterns
I have an event whose message field I want to match against multiple patterns, if the message matches any of the patterns, then simply stop searching the remaining patterns in the list/array and write to output.
For reference this is all I could find on the site.
It says

If you need to match multiple patterns against a single field, the
value can be an array of patterns:

The issue here is that both of the following filters work , by work I mean Logstash doesn't error out, so they're both syntactically correct.
What exactly is the difference between the following 2 filters ?
FILTER 1
filter {
    if [fields][component][0] in ["data_vm"]  {
        grok {
            patterns_dir => "/usr/share/logstash/patterns"
            match => ["message", "(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{DATA:thread}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message_r}", "(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{DATA:thread}%{SPACE}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message_r}", "(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{DATA:thread}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{DATA:logger_class}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message_r}"]
            add_field => {"dhiwakar_new" => "%{message_r}"}
        }
    }
}

FILTER 2
filter {
    if [fields][component][0] in ["data_vm"]  {
        grok {
            patterns_dir => "/usr/share/logstash/patterns"
            match => { "message" => ["(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{DATA:thread}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message_r}", "(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{DATA:thread}%{SPACE}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message_r}", "(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{DATA:thread}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{DATA:logger_class}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message_r}"]}
            add_field => {"dhiwakar_new" => "%{message_r}"}
        }
    }
}

